# Как получить id всех тэгов с определенным классом?

Tags: javascript

На странице выводятся циклом блоки, у каждого уникальный id.

```
{% for product in slots %}
    <div class="block-product-main" id="{{product.id}}">
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

необходимо у каждого элемента считать id:

```
let elements = document.querySelectorAll('.block-product-main')
for(i in elements){
    console.log(i.id)
}
```

С js не никогда не работал, поэтому возникают сложности... понимаю, что возможно нельзя таким образом получить id, но как это сделать мыслей нет. Буду благодарен за помощь!

Comment: А это что за язык в котором вы html писали?

Comment: Ну а вообще вы правильно писали. Так и получают id элементов

Comment: @eccs0103 Не не совсем )

Comment: @SwaD так это `for...in` я что-то `for...of` увидел

Comment: Достаточно вместо `in` писать `of` и получится.

Comment: @eccs0103 Там вторя засада, попадают не элементы, свойства типа length

Comment: @eccs0103 это шаблонизатор встроенный в django

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Осуществить выборку всех id тегов, которые имеют определнный класс можно, выбрав все теги методом **querySelectorAll**, а далее пробежать по полученной коллекции

```js
let elements = document.querySelectorAll('.block-product-main');
elements.forEach(el => console.log(el.id));
```

```html
<div id='id1' class='block-product-main'>1</div>
<div id='id2' class='block-product-main'>2</div>
<div id='id3' class='block-product-main'>3</div>
```

Если надо сохранить все, лучше использовать массив

```js
let elements = document.querySelectorAll('.block-product-main');
const arrId = [];
elements.forEach(el => arrId.push(el.id));
        
console.log(arrId)
```

```html
<div id='id1' class='block-product-main'>1</div>
<div id='id2' class='block-product-main'>2</div>
<div id='id3' class='block-product-main'>3</div>
```

Перебирать коллекцию `for in` не самая хорошая затея, т.к. помимо самих элементов, там есть методы и свойства:

```js
let elements = document.querySelectorAll('.block-product-main');

for (let x in elements) {
  console.log(x, elements[x])
}
```

```html
<div id='id1' class='block-product-main'>1</div>
<div id='id2' class='block-product-main'>2</div>
<div id='id3' class='block-product-main'>3</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`for...in` обычно для перебора объектов используют. Для итераторов используйте `for...of`:

```js
let elements = document.querySelectorAll('.block-product-main')
for (const elem of elements) {
  console.log(elem.id)
}
```

#### Дополнение к [ответу SwaD](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1492723/324730)

Если нужно в массив собрать:

```js
const arrId = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.block-product-main')).map(elem => elem.id);
```

Comment: Может лучше ссылку на ответ поставить, а не на меня? ) У меня в профиле ответов на этот вопрос нет...

Comment: @SwaD ну думаю читающий догадается искать ответ от пользователя с ником SwaD или же зайти посмотреть кто же такой этот SwaD... хотя скорее... сейчас, поменяю

Comment: Вот я бы сначала ткнул, понял что не туда ушел, вернулся бы и начал искать )